# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: laravel-5

im new in php.

im about to make landing  page. every file are right in the folder. Idk why i get error like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r06yE.jpg)

this is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
<title>Ortwo School Management System</title> 
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/css/animate.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/css/plugins/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/formvalidation/dist/css/formValidation.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="{{ asset('templates/admin/css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/sweetalert.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@section("css")
@show
```

```
    <script src="{{ asset('templates/admin/js/jquery-2.1.1.js') }}">
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('templates/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}">
    </script>
    <script src="{{ 
    asset('templates/admin/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js') }}">
    </script>
    <script src="{{ 
    asset('templates/admin/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') 
    }}"></script>

    <!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
    <script src="{{ asset('templates/admin/js/inspinia.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('templates/admin/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js') 
    }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('templates/admin/js/plugins/wow/wow.min.js') }}">
    </script>
```

pls somebody help me..
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you haven't executed the code, you have just opened a blade template file in a browser (see url with 'file' prefix). You should open the page via a route url defined in the routes/web.php file in your application.

Comment: thx for the attention.. i was open it from route before i check the html file directly to browser like that. anyway that is a clone, and when i did the cloning, i forgot to make a new .env file. T_T